# opening npy array. can view but not index?

Tags: python, numpy

I created a dictionary with different arrays and stored it as an npy file. When I open it I can print and visually inspect the dictionary, but I can not index it or work with it in anyway. Using the `.shape` method returns ().

Maybe an example will make it clear:

```
import numpy as np

a = dict()    
a["arr"] = np.array([1,2,3])

np.save("a.npy", a, allow_pickle=True)

a = np.load("a.npy", allow_pickle=True)
a
```

This will return the output:

```
array({'arr': array([1, 2, 3])}, dtype=object)
```

but when I index:

```
a[0]
```

I get:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

I can't iterate over it either.

Is there a way for me to retrieve this array? I dont want to spend an other 6 hours preparing the data.

Comment: Don't you mean to do `a["arr"][0]`?

Comment: a["arr"] returns: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: `np.save` saves NumPy arrays, not arbitrary objects.

Comment: so ill have to redo it? i kinda figured that already

Comment: It's in a 0d array; index with 0 values.  `a[()]`